# I thymeleaf how to use page parameter as property key?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

There is such redirection in Controller:

```
return "redirect:login?message=login.registered";
```

In html template I want to show property's value for `login.registered` key.

In jsp it was just:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
...
<spring:message code="${param.message}"/>
```

How to do the same using Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in thymeleaf, you can do this with the #messages object.  This should work:

```
<div th:text="${#messages.msg(param.message)}" />
```